# regex search and replace left and right boundary

Tags: regex

For the given string,

```
I can haz haz bacon. Mmmm. Tasty, tasty bacon.
       ↑                            ↑
```

I want to capture content bounded by the **first** string "`az`" and the **last** string "`as`".

In this example I cannot use `^$` anchors. I tried using:

```
\b(az).*(as)\b.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just `az.*as`?

Comment: The problem is that you used word boundaries `\b`, remove them and your expression should work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would find the longest possible match:

```
(?<=az).*(?=as)
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/wzPdbrmbov

For shortest match:

```
(?<=az).*?(?=as)
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/GoPgYpGyI7